# GhostScript generating damaged tiff file

Tags: ghostscript

I am trying to generate tiff file using ghost script from a pdf. 
I am using this command

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2  -r450x635 -sDEVICE=tiffgray -sCompression=lzw  -sOutputFile=test2_local.tif  foil.pdf
```

The tiff file is getting generated but it is not opening and i am getting message of damaged file. If I reduce resolution then it works fine. And it also works if remove the compression.

But i can not remove compression as file size generated is 174MB. I am using GS 9.22 on mac OS.

Comment: What is telling you that the file is damaged ? Very possibly your TIFF reader simply can't cope with BigTiff files, what are the dimensions of the input file ?

Comment: damaged file error is coming with smaller size. so when i use -sCompression. It generates file of size 200KB, but that file is coming as damaged.I tried to open with preview and adobe photoshop.

Comment: Well to be honest, there's not much anyone can say without looking at an example. You probably need to post a link to an input PDF file which doesn't work, to go along with the command line.

Comment: this is test pdf  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=88827935044935276560 i am using same command as given above

Comment: I've tried this with 9.22 and the current code and I can't reproduce a problem. For me your command line and file produces a TIFF file which is 481,292 bytes in size and opens in Adobe Photoshop without error. I notice you are running on a Mac, how did you build Ghostscript ? Are you using a shared libtiff ? I'll try an old MacOS machine on Monday.

Comment: Tried it on a Mac running 10.8, built Ghostscript from scratch; git clone, ./autogen.sh, make.... Used the command line and file above. The file refuses to open in Preview giving the 'may be damaged' error. Copied the same file to a Windows box and opened it with Photoshop 5 without complaint so I don't think there's a real problem with the file. The file is an Intel format TIFF file but the size in pixels doens't look like it should be a problem. Nevertheless, I don't think this is a Ghostscript problem, the TIFF file I generate appears to be valid.